# Problem in saving filenames in my list using if loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf

I have written a code which basically selects the first pdf from all folders and then extracts text data from all the pdfs.
I am saving these extracted pdf text data to a dataframe. I also want to save the names of the pdf files to my dataframe, the problem is that, it keeps writing the recent pdf file name in my dataframe and ignores the rest of the pdf file names.

Here's my code:

```
folders = ['F:/a/b/input_data/Sample documents/xyz/',
           'F:/a/b/input_data/Sample documents/abc/',
           'F:/a/b/input_data/Sample documents/pqr/']
allmypdfs = []
for folder in folders:
    alllfiles = os.listdir(folder)
    firstpdfs = ""
    for i in alllfiles:
        if '.pdf' or '.PDF' in i:
            firstpdfs = i
            print('PDF-Names--', firstpdfs)
            break
    with open(folder + firstpdfs, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
        texts = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', '', text)  # to remove \x0c escape chars
        allmypdfs.append(texts)

# dataframe creation
data = {'PDF NAME': firstpdfs, 'Text Data': [allmypdfs]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.explode('Text Data')
print(df1.head(50))
```

I have tried creating a dataframe for capturing pdf file names in the if loop and later append it to text data, but that doesn't get the proper ouput(As it keeps creating a new dataframe everytime in the if loop).
I have also tried creating an empty list first and then appending the filenames but that gives me a None in the output.
Like this

```
allmypdfs = []
files = []
for folder in folders:
    alllfiles = os.listdir(folder)
    firstpdfs = ""
    for i in alllfiles:
        if '.pdf' or '.PDF' in i:
            firstpdfs = i
            print('PDF-Names--', files.append(firstpdfs))
            break
    with open(folder + firstpdfs, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
        texts = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', '', text)  # to remove \x0c escape chars
        allmypdfs.append(texts)
```

This gives me an output like  `PDF-Names-- None`
The output that I want should look something like

```
0 PDF NAME Text Data
0 1.pdf     ofkndv....
1 2.pdf     dfgnnrjon...
```

The output that I get is :

```
0 PDF NAME Text Data
0 1.pdf     ofkndv....
1 1.pdf     dfgnnrjon...
```

Please help me understand how do I make it work in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method `append()` from a `list` object returns `None`, `print('PDF-Names--', files.append(firstpdfs))` must print `PDF-Names-- None` on your console.

I guess, what you intended was something like this:

```py
# print file name of first PDF found in this folder
print('PDF-Names--', firstpdfs)
# append file name to list of files
files.append(firstpdfs)
```

Regarding your data frame, you build the dictionary after the loop, in which only `firstpdfs` is the name of the first PDF in the last folder you have visited.
You are creating a table from a single dictionary (`{'PDF NAME': firstpdfs, 'Text Data': [allmypdfs]}`). However, it was intended to create one from a *list of dictionaries*.
Go with this schema

```py
data_list = []
for folder_name in folders:
    # TODO: first PDF files in the directory <folder_name> and return <file_name>
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fh:
        # TODO: extract text from file and return as binary string in variable <text>
    # store data in a dictionary and append to the list
    data_list.append({'PDF NAME': file_name, 'Text Data': text})
# convert list of dictionaries to pandas.DataFrame object
data = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```

You may want to aim for a more concise naming and condensed writing (wirte little functions as they are easier to maintain and debugg) in order to avoid loosing the overview on the code